# Research Assistant Badge Progress Incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I seem to be having a problem with my tag wiki edits registering in the system. If I go to edit any badge, the page states that I have completed 3 tag wiki edits

[image: 3 tag wiki edits]

However, when I go to view my reputation page, I have more tag wiki edits than that

[image: 6 tag wiki edits]

The edits were done on March 5th, March 18th, and today. So I don't think there is a problem with time, except for the one for today.

Comment: Perhaps one of the counts doesn't consider the *excerpt* to be a distinct edit.

Comment: The excerpt doesn't count.

Answer (score 2):

This is a count of the number of tags you edited. So if you edited both the excerpt and body of *one* tag, it only counts as *one* tag edit into the Research Assistant badge.

Comment: They were all excerpts except for one.

Comment: Excerpts don't count for Research Assistant, only full tag-wiki edits.  (Learned that the hard way on another site.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Then how did I get any progress at all?

Comment: The one that's not an excerpt would count.  I can't see your screenshots here at work (thanks IT); are you saying that you've only done one tag wiki but you have credit for more than one?

Comment: I'm saying I have done 7 but I have credit for 3